# How can we prove this inequality involving e?

Tags: calculus, inequality

$$ \frac{1}{1+|x|} \le \frac{e^x - 1}{x} \le1 + |x|(e - 2) $$ where $$x \in [-1,0)\cup(0,1]$$

How can we prove this inequality? My text used it to prove the limit of the middle function when $x→0$ which is $1$ using sandwich theorem.

I have no idea how to begin. I know I can find the limit using L'Hospital but still I cant figure out where did this inequality come from.

Comment: Any answer will depend on particular definition of $e^x$. You might want to include how you've defined it.

Comment: In how many ways can you define e^x ? I think there is only one ?

Comment: Many. Please see [characterizations of exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function).

Comment: The second one it is the value of the infinite series .

Comment: What's wrong with just taking separately into account the part $x >0$ and $x < 0$ and differentiating?

Comment: @ant differentiating what ?

Comment: Take the difference between the two functions and compute the minimum in $(0,1)$ (using the derivatives). If the minimum is bigger than $0$, one of the two functions is bigger than the other

Comment: Isn't there any easier way that way must be the last option to prove something .

Comment: @RaghavSingal Yeah, I agree it's not the smartest way but it usually works and it doesn't require much mental effort, it's just some computations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the series definition it immediately follows that $e^x\geq 1 + x$: by uniqueness of Taylor series, the first derivative at $0$ is $1$, so $1+x$ is tangent - inequality follows by convexity of $e^x$.

**1.** $\frac{e^x-1}{x}\geq\frac 1{1+|x|}$

If $x>0$, then $e^x\geq 1 + x$ implies

$$\frac{e^x-1}x\geq 1\geq \frac 1{1+|x|}.$$

If $x<0$, then we have

\begin{align}
\frac{e^x-1}{x}\geq\frac 1{1+|x|}&\iff e^x - 1\leq \frac x{1-x}\\
&\iff e^x \leq 1+\frac x{1-x}\\
&\iff e^x \leq \frac 1{1-x}\\
&\iff 1 - x \leq e^{-x}\\
&\iff 1 + t \leq e^{t}
\end{align}

**2.** $\frac{e^x-1}{x}\leq 1+|x|(e-2)$

For $x > 0$, we have

\begin{align}\frac{e^x-1}{x}\leq 1+|x|(e-2) &\iff e^x-1\leq x+x^2(e-2)\\
&\iff \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\leq e-2\\
&\iff \frac 1{2!}+\frac x{3!}+\ldots\leq \frac 1{2!} + \frac1{3!}+\ldots\\
\end{align}

If $x<0$, then $$e^x\geq 1 + x \implies e^x-1\geq x\implies \frac{e^x-1}{x}\leq 1 \leq 1+|x|(e-2)$$

Comment: Can you elaborate the last step ? How is e^x greater than 1+x if x is negative?

Comment: @Raghav Singal, as I said in the first line, $x + 1$ is tangent line at $0$, while $e^x$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped !! Give you a plus one :)

Answer (score 1):

*HINT/Partial Solution*

Consider the case where $x\lt0$.

Let's work on the left part inequality $$\frac{1}{1-x}\le\frac{e^x-1}{x}\Rightarrow\\\text{(since $x$ is negative)}\\\frac{x}{1-x}\ge e^x-1\Rightarrow\\e^x(x-1)\le1$$

Let $g(x)=e^x(x-1)$ , $x\in[-1,0)$

We have $$g'(x)=xe^x\lt0, \forall x\in[-1,0)\Rightarrow\\ \text{ g($x$) is increasing in $[-1,0)$ }\Rightarrow\\x\le0\Rightarrow g(x)\le g(0)=1$$
as desired.

For the right part of the inequality, that is $$\frac{e^x-1}{x}\le1-x(e-2)$$
we can work in the same manner, by considering the function $h(x)=e^x-x+x^2(e-2)-1$ (here, you will need to see what happens with $h''(x)$ to find the monotony of $h$).

The same approach can be applied for the $x\gt0$ case.

Answer (score 1):

Power series algebra is your friend here. We have:

$$\frac{1}{1+|x|}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i|x|^i=1-|x|+|x|^2-|x|^3+\cdots$$

$$\frac{e-1}{x}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{(i+1)!}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\cdots$$

$$1+|x|(e-2)=1-|x|+x|x|+\frac{1}{2}x^2|x|+\frac{1}{6}x^3|x|+\cdots$$

To see that the first is less than the second, notice that when $1>x>0$ the first is less than $1$ and the second is greater than $1$. When $-1<x<0$, using the Lagrange Error formula tells you that the second is greater than the first. Thus the second is always greater than the first.

See if you can come up with an argument for why the third is greater than the second.

Comment: What is lagranges error formula ?

Comment: @RaghavSingal Have you ever seen Taylor series before? I had assumed so, since you said that $e$ was defined via infinite series...

Comment: Not exactly though I know the Mclaurin series which is its speacial case I think ?

Comment: It's a way to bound how much the error is when you truncate an infinite series. The calculation is a little messy though, and so I would recommend using the proof given in @jacaboul 's answer to complete my answer rather than Lagrange Error Bounds.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds awkard to use these inequalities to prove the limit you want.

The limit $\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x-1)/x=1$ follows by L'Hospital's rule as you said, or by using the fact that $(e^x-1)/x=1+\sum_{n\ge 1} x^n/(n+1)!$ and that the power series $\sum_{n\ge 1} x^n/(n+1)!$ is absolutely convergent and hence the sum converges to $0$ as $x\to 0$. If you are not convinced of that at sight you may use  $|\sum_{n\ge 1} x^n/(n+1)!|\le |x|\sum_{n\ge 0} |x|^n/(n+2)!\le |x|e^{|x|}$.

Now to prove the inequality $(e^x-1)/x\le 1+|x|(e-2)$ here are some hints. First note that the case $x\in [-1,0[$ follows from the case $x\in ]0,1]$, since for $x<0$ we have $(e^x-1)/x=(e^{-|x|}-1)/(-|x|)=(1-e^{-|x|})/|x|=(e^{|x|}-1)/(|x|e^{|x|})\le (e^{|x|}-1)/|x|$, since $e^u\ge 1$ if $u\ge 0$. Now let's concentrate on the case $x\in I=]0,1]$. In that case we may write
$(e^x-1)/x=1+x\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n/(n+2)!\le 1+x\sum_{n\ge 0}1/(n+2)!=1+x(e-2)$.
I didn't try, but I guess similar arguments may handle the other inequality. I hope this helps.